# Drupal href is not working

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7

```
<ul>
<li class="list">
  <a href="/node/123">
     <div class="image">
        image tag
     </div>
     <div class="text">
        <p class="title">title</p>
        <p>Welcome</p>
     </div>
  </a>
</ul>
```

I click on image or text is it not opening to the href link, but if open new tab is working, also I tried with href full path but its not working

Comment: Add relevant tags. Although it is important not to spam with tags it is also a good idea to tag it accurately (i.e. this will probably need those who know both drupal and html)

Comment: Does the link not navigate? Or does the link navigate but not open the node you expect? More information is needed to help you.

Comment: "but if I open new tab is working" - what does that means? You must explain this better.

Answer (score 0):

You can define
 l(t('Link text'), 'about-us'); 
inside your php tag it will help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Plz check ur javascript whether onclick event is disable or not 
Example:

```
el.onclick = function (e) {
e.stopPropagation()
e.preventDefault()
}
```

This is disable the click event.

Answer (score 0):

It may be your css/javascript issue.

If you want to validate your html check it in https://jsfiddle.net.

I copy/pasted your above-mentioned code into HTML section the clicked on run button. The link [**`<a href="/node/123">`**] is working fine.

You can check z-index or another thing.